# Count strings in nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
sentences = [
    ["my", "first", "question", "in", "stackoverflow", "is", "my", "favorite"], 
    ["my", "favorite", "language", "is", "python"]
]
```

I want to get the count of each word in the `sentences` list. So, my output should look as follows.

```
{
    'stackoverflow': 1,
     'question': 1,
     'is': 2,
     'language': 1,
     'first': 1,
     'in': 1,
     'favorite': 2,
     'python': 1,
     'my': 3
}
```

I am currently doing it as follows.

```
frequency_input = [item for sublist in sentences for item in sublist]
frequency_output = dict(
    (x,frequency_input.count(x)) 
    for x in set(frequency_input)
)
```

However, it is not efficient at all for long lists. I have a really long list with about 1 million sentences in the list. It took me two days to run it, and it is still running.

In that case I would like to make my programme more efficient. My current first line of the code is `O(n^2)` and my second line is `O(n)`. Please let me know if there is a more efficient way of doing this in python. It would be reaaly ideal if I could run it with lesser time than now. I am not worried about space complexity.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simpler and more performant approach would be to flatten the lists using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), and to count the strings with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

Counter(chain.from_iterable(sentences))

Counter({'my': 3,
         'first': 1,
         'question': 1,
         'in': 1,
         'stackoverflow': 1,
         'is': 2,
         'favorite': 2,
         'language': 1,
         'python': 1})
```

Comment: @yatu thank you for the great answer. I tried your code in my real dataset and it works like magic. Its definitely effective. I think it is O(n). Thank you very much :)

Comment: @EmJ It's actually O(_n_ log _m_), where _m_ is the number of distinct words to be counted (inserting into a set is a O(log _n_) operation).

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you. It is interesting to know that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter class from collections module.

if you want to learn the number of words in each sentence **separately** you can do as follows

```
from collections import Counter

sentences = [["my", "first", "question", "in", "stackoverflow", "is", "my", "favorite"], ["my", "favorite", "language", "is", "python"]]

counter_list = [dict(Counter(sentence)) for sentence in sentences]
print(counter_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'my': 2, 'first': 1, 'question': 1, 'in': 1, 'stackoverflow': 1, 'is': 1, 'favorite': 1}, {'my': 1, 'favorite': 1, 'language': 1, 'is': 1, 'python': 1}]
```

Or if you want total word counts you can use chain method from itertools module.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

sentences = [["my", "first", "question", "in", "stackoverflow", "is", "my", "favorite"], ["my", "favorite", "language", "is", "python"]]

sentences = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sentences))
word_counts = Counter(sentences)
print(word_counts)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'my': 3, 'is': 2, 'favorite': 2, 'first': 1, 'question': 1, 'in': 1, 'stackoverflow': 1, 'language': 1, 'python': 1})
```

The complexity of Counter object as [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) show, Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. So constructing counter object from an iterable has the time complexity of O(n)

Answer (score 0):

`sentences = [["my", "first", "question", "in", "stackoverflow", "is", "my", "favorite"], ["my", "favorite", "language", "is", "python"]]`

`combinedList = []`

## combine the list of array of words into a single array

`def my_function (my_list):
    for list in my_list:
        combinedList.extend(list)
        print(combinedList)
my_function(sentences)`

## use count functionality over the array of words

`countData = {}`

`for word in combinedList:
    countData[word] = combinedList.count(word)`

## countData will have the count for each of the words

Comment: Approach here is use to spread the list data. Then simply use the count method to get the number for each word.